# How to redirect to cart after adding product to cart programmatically

Tags: magento2, cart, addtocart, redirect, plugin

I want to redirect to cart page after adding the product into cart,
I know there is a provision in config but I have a custom product type and that config is not working for that product.

That configuration setting is working for simple and other products but not for the custom product type.

So Is there any way I can do this thing **programmatically** using plugins or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

1. > app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
       <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add">
           <plugin name="interceptAddProductToCartRedirect" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Cart\Add" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
       </type>
   </config>
   ```
2. > app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/Checkout/Cart/Add.php

   ```
   <?php

   namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Cart;

   use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;
   use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

   class Add
   {
       protected $url;
       protected $request;
       protected $logger;

       public function __construct(
           UrlInterface $url,
           Http $request,
           LoggerInterface $logger
       )
       {
           $this->_url = $url;
           $this->_request = $request;
           $this->_logger = $logger;
       }

       /**
        * Redirect to checkout/cart after Adding product to cart
        *
        * @param \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject
        * @param \Closure $proceed
        * @return mixed
        */
       public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject, \Closure $proceed)
       {
           $result = $proceed();
           $this->_logger->info("Add to cart plugin OK");
           if (!$this->_request->isAjax()) {
               $result->setUrl($this->_url->getUrl('checkout/cart'));
               return $result;
           }
           return $result;
       }
   }
   ```
3. > app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
       <body>
           <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart">
               <action method="setTemplate">
                   <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/view/addtocart.phtml</argument>
               </action>
           </referenceBlock>
       </body>
   </page>
   ```
4. copy `addtocart.phtml` from :

   > vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\addtocart.phtml

   into :

   > app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product\view\addtocart.phtml

   then add `"bindSubmit": true` like this :

   ```
   <script type="text/x-magento-init">
   {
       "#product_addtocart_form": {
           "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {
               "bindSubmit": true, <!-- HERE -->
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. > generate DI configuration & flush cache storage

   ```
   php bin/magento s:d:c
   php bin/magento c:f
   ```

   <sup>Good luck.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

**please refere the below links. This may help you.**

https://magento-qa.com/how-can-i-redirect-to-the-cart-page-programmatically

[How can I redirect to the cart page programmatically?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/331631/how-can-i-redirect-to-the-cart-page-programmatically)