# How can I redirect to the cart page programmatically?

Tags: magento2, addtocart

I'm using this plugin **in order to prevent a product be added more than one time** and it works perfectly but I'd like to add a feature: instead to stay on the product page once the product is added more than one time, I'd like to check if the backend option `Stores->Configuration->Sales->Checkout->Shopping Cart->After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart` is enabled and redirect if it is.

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Checkout_Cart_BeforeAddToCart" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Cart\BeforeAddToCart"/>
</type>
```

**vendor/module/Plugin/Magento/Checkout/Cart/BeforeAddToCart.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Cart;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Proxy as SessionProxy;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;

class BeforeAddToCart {

    protected $messageManager;
    protected $cartSession;
    protected $configurableProduct;

    public function __construct(
        Configurable $configurableProduct,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        SessionProxy $cartSession
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->cartSession = $cartSession;
        $this->configurableProduct = $configurableProduct;
    }

    public function beforeAddProduct(Cart $subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo=null)
    {
        $enableProductCartControl=true;

        $product = null;
        $parentProduct=null;

        if ($productInfo instanceof Product) {

            $product = $productInfo;
            if (!$product->getId()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __("The product wasn't found. Verify the product and try again.")
                );
            }

        }

        if ($product)
        {
            if ($product->getTypeId()==='configurable')
            {
                if (isset($requestInfo['super_attribute']))
                {
                    $parentProduct=$product;
                    $childProduct = $this->configurableProduct->getProductByAttributes($requestInfo['super_attribute'] ,$product);
                    // change $product to child
                    $product=$childProduct;
                }
            }

            if ($product->getTypeId()==='grouped')
            {
                if (isset($requestInfo['super_group']))
                {
                    $parentProduct=$product;
                    //$childProduct = // get child from grouped...
                    // change $product to child
                    //$product=$childProduct;
                }
            }
                if ($product && $enableProductCartControl)
                {
                    // check for existence of product in cart...
                    //
                    if($this->cartSession->getQuote()->hasProductId($product->getId())){
                        
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                            __("This product is already in the cart. Testing, testing : ". $product->getSku())
                        );
                    }

                }


        }

        return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];

    }

    /**
     * Get request for product add to cart procedure
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject|int|array $requestInfo
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    private function _getProductRequest($requestInfo)
    {
        if ($requestInfo instanceof \Magento\Framework\DataObject) {
            $request = $requestInfo;
        } elseif (is_numeric($requestInfo)) {
            $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['qty' => $requestInfo]);
        } elseif (is_array($requestInfo)) {
            $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($requestInfo);
        } else {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('We found an invalid request for adding product to quote.')
            );
        }
        return $request;
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the answer to your original question with the cart redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the plugin is working with `Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` you can simply set a redirect url in the session

```
$this->session->setRedirectUrl($this->url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index'));
```

Inject the following classes

```
 Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session 
 Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
```

Comment: Thanks @paj. It partially works. I mean, it redirect to the cart page even if the product is already present but it doesn't check the backend option `Stores->Configuration->Sales->Checkout->Shopping Cart->After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart`. Furthermore, once redirected it shows this message `We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now.`.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ns3vSdFr

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use the `vendor/magento/module-checkout/Helper/Cart.php` helper's method `getShouldRedirectToCart()` to check if your configuration is enabled.
2. You can use the same helper's `getCartUrl()` method to retrieve the URL of the cart page.
3. Inject in your plugin constructor the `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory` class and store it in a private property called `$resultFactory`, then use it like this to redirect to cart the desirec URL (just store the cart url in the *$redirectUrl* variable):

```
 /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
$resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$resultRedirect->setUrl($redirectUrl);
```